# Django templates in subdirectory

Tags: python, django

I've set a directory in settings.py to look at templates:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/var/www/templates/',
)
```

With a dir structure like

```
/var/www/templates/
|__footer.html
|__header.html
|__index/
   |__index.html
```

I can source header and footer fine

```
>>> render_to_response('footer.html')
    <django.http.response.HttpResponse object at 0x2268d10>
```

But not in the subdir

```
>>> render_to_response('index/index.html')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 29, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 172, in render_to_string
    return t.render(Context(dictionary))
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 166, in render
    template = get_template(template_name)
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 146, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/var/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 139, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check setting django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader in TEMPLATE_LOADERS, If it's not already there try to add it like this -

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

django document on template subdirectories -  
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-subdirectories

Comment: I think PROJECT_PATH needs to use `__file__` and I've tried with inits, but no luck (I believe the look ups of templates is a walk, not import.

Comment: Yep, added those too.

Comment: Is this worked for you ? If not, try adding your app path in INSTALLED_APPS setting in settings.py file.
INSTALLED_APPS {
  www.templates
}
/var/ should be in your PYTHONPATH.